# Pass value of variable to new class instance (keep value and not empty variable)

Tags: php, oop

Im struggling with this problem for 2 days. I made a simple example.

Im having 3 files. I invoke classes. I set value **doors** inside one of these objects. 
What i need? I need to pass this value to object Bus but it keeps removing the value. Is there any way to keep value and pass it to class Bus?

**oop.php**

```
 <?php
        include_once("oop_class_1.php");
        include_once("oop_class_2.php");


        $doors = 5;

        $d = new Car();
        $d->setDoors($doors);

        $g = new Bus();
        echo $g->getDoors();
 ?>
```

**oop_class_1.php**

```
<?php

class Car
{
    public $doors;

        public function setDoors($doors) 
        {
            $this->doors = $doors;
        }

}
?>
```

**oop_class_2.php**

```
<?php

class Bus extends Car
{
    public function getDoors()
    {
        return $this->doors; // tried static call Car::doors but doesnt work either...
    }

}
?>
```

Thanks anyone for help. I really have no clue.

Comment: Bus extends the Car class, thats does not mean that a new Bus will automatically contain a value in an already created Car Object

Comment: When you Extend Car with Bus, you give Bus the Properties and Methods of Car but not the values that existed in a previous Car.

Comment: And is there any way to pass values that existed in previous Car?

Comment: Why would you. The previous Car is a Car and not a Bus. They are not in fact anything to do with each other. Their Classes just share a `door` property for convenience. The eventual instantiated Bus Object has as many doors as it has. It does not always have the number of doors a Car has

Comment: Remember if you create these objects the other way round, i.e. Bus before Car the Class/Object must still be able to work

Answer (score 2):

That's not how OOP works. If you create a `Bus` instance, it inherits all properties and methods from the `Car` class, there is no need to create a `Car` instance. Separate objects are not connected in any way!

So in your case, you should just do the following:

```
$doors = 5;

$d = new Bus();
$d->setDoors($doors);  // Calls the function `setDoors` inherited from its parent class
echo $d->getDoors();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
include_once("oop_class_1.php");
include_once("oop_class_2.php");
$doors = 5;

$d = new Car();
$d->setDoors($doors);

$g = new Bus();
echo $g->getDoors();
```

What do you see if you `echo $d->getDoors();`?

THAT is the instance you set the number of doors on, not on $g.